# Django - How to import csv data with a model that has a foreign key to an instance of the same model?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, migration

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file on a model Category that looks something like this:

```
class Categories(BaseModel):

    shop_id = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name_fr = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am working on a script to load the csv and read the data to create a model instance, but how can I get the `Categories` instance related to `parent_id` when it has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

So your foreign fields shouldn't end with `_id` (`parent_id` in this case). This is because django would accept or return the integer id of that foreign key when you add on `_id`. Makes more sense with this example here:

```py
catgeory = Categories.objects.first()
parent_category = Categories.objects.last()

category.parent = parent_category
category.save()

print(category.parent) # <Categories object...>
print(category.parent_id) # "1"
```

Now i believe your code would have to do `category.parent_id_id` which looks  weird.

Anyway this might work?:

```py
categories_to_create = []

for row in csv:
  c = Categories(parent_id_id=row[1], shop_id=row[0]...)
  categories_to_create.append(c)

Categories.objects.bulk_create(categories_to_create)
```

Im not sure if that will work, if it doesnt, maybe you can try reading the csv straight into your database, for example if you are using postgres, [this might help](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/)

EDIT:

Also if all else fails. First create the objects without setting the parent_id. Then go in and fill the parent id with a loop afterwards :)